# Sanity check for my logic in a "tree" like problem

Tags: probability, proof-verification

There is a bomber who is sent to destroy a target.
Prob(bomber reach target)=$0.6$
Prob(BOMB hit target)=$0.5$
Prob(target destroyed by bomb)=$0.8$

We send 1 bomber which carry 5 bombs to a target, what is the chance that it destroys it?

What I have done is as follows:

Each bomb has $0.5*0.8=0.4$ chance to hit & destroy a target which means $0.6$ chance to leave the target unaffected.

So $5$ bombs has $(0.6)^5=\dfrac{243}{3125}$ chance to not affect the target.

So the prob that 1 bomber with 5 bombs won't kill a target is: $0.4 + 0.6*\dfrac{243}{3125}=0.4466$

This means that the chance that it will destroy the target is $1-0.4466=0.5533$

Is that the right way of doing it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\color{green}\checkmark$ That was a little long winded, but yes, the correct approach.

You're after the probability that the bomber reaches the target and that the five bombs don't all fail to hit and destroy it.

$\mathsf P(\textsf{reach})~\Big(1-\big(1-\mathsf P(\textsf{hit}\mid\textsf{reach})~\mathsf P(\textsf{destroy}\mid\textsf{hit})\big)^5\Big)\\= (0.6)\Big(1-\big(1-(0.5)(0.8)\big)^5\big)\\=0.553344$

Comment: Oh I see thanks I was in the mindset of "always finding the negative" and doing "$1-$" I see now I could drop the "or" part I did at the end and just go straight into the chance I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the approach is right. The answer is right except that you rounded in the wrong direction and didn't indicate that you rounded.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by rounding in the wrong direction? is it my final $0.5533$ answer?

Comment: @TheOne: No, the intermediate result $0.4466$. The exact value is $0.446656$, which rounds to $0.4467$. You can also see the problem in $ 1-0.4466=0.5533$, where two rounded numbers fail to add up to an integer, which they should unless they're both exactly half-integers. But actually my bigger gripe is that you wrote $=$ instead of $\approx$. This is mathematics, not engineering ;-)